# Call custom client side validation function after WebForm_OnSubmit? .NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, client-side-validation

I want to run a simple JS function after my .NET validator controls run their javascript.
My onsubmit value is javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();, which seems to be generated automatically and I can't change it.

Am I right in assuming I need to just add a function in this field to get it to work? Also, my form is validating after a field has been changed (not once the form has been submitted), which is great, but is there a setting soimewhere to turn that on/off?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Althought it is a late answer I will post for future.
If your aspx page is a simple page (no ContentPage, so no MasterPage) you can add onsubmit function directly on the markup:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return myCustomValidation();"... >
```

`"WebForm_OnSubmit()"` will be executed first and then if validation is ok `"myCustomValidation()"` will be executed.

If your aspx page is a ContentPage (so it has a MasterPage) you don't have access to markup in order to do the same as before. You can set `"myCustomValidation()"` to be executed after `"WebForm_OnSubmit()"` in code behind:

```
Private Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    If Not Page.ClientScript.IsOnSubmitStatementRegistered(Me.GetType, "aspxMyCustomValidation") Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType, "aspxMyCustomValidation", "myCustomValidation()")
    End If
End Sub
```

The key is to set this code in `"PreRenderComplete"` event and not in `"Load"` event, in order to execute `"myCustomValidation()"` after `"WebForm_OnSubmit()"`.